# Greedy machine scheduling in javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, scheduling, greedy

Consider a single machine scheduling problem, where we are given a set, T, of tasks specified by their start times and finish times, as in the task scheduling problem, except now we have only one machine and we wish to maximize the number of tasks that this single machine performs. Design a greedy algorithm for this single machine scheduling problem and show that it is correct. What is the running time of this algorithm?

**ATTEMPT**

```
 var machineScheduling = function(T, finish_time, i, jobs) {
    var max_jobs = [];

    (function rec(){
        if (i < 0 || T[i-1][0] === 0) {
            if (jobs.length > max_jobs.length) max_jobs = jobs;
            return 0;
        }

        var new_finish_time = T[i-1][0];
        var new_jobs = jobs.slice();

        var A = rec(finish_time, i-1, new_jobs);
        var B = 1+rec(new_finish_time, i-1, new_jobs.push(i));

        return Math.max(A, B);
    })(T, finish_time, T.length, []);
 };
```

Comment: Can include example parameters passed to function at Question ?

Comment: Unfortunately I didnt receive any